# Linux routing table entry disappears

Tags: linux, routing

I run Fedora 20 (Linux 3.13.3-201.fc20.i686) inside VirtualBox on a Windows 7 SP1 host. The Ethernet adapter on the guest is configured as a Bridged Adapter in VBox, and gets an IP via DHCP. Here's the routing table on the guest:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         router          255.255.255.255 UGH   1024   0        0 p2p1
default         router          0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 p2p1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p2p1
```

Every so often (every day, perhaps), the 1st entry in the routing table disappears; as a result, I can make outbound connections to the intranet, but not to the Internet.

How do I find out who's modifying the routing table? Are there logs I could look at?